# find the volume of a tetrahedron with three mutually perpendicular faces and three mutually perpendicular edges with lengths 3 cm, 4 cm, and 5 cm

Tags: calculus, integration

find the volume of a tetrahedron with three mutually perpendicular faces and three mutually perpendicular edges with lengths 3 cm, 4 cm, and 5 cm

i've never seen an example like this before.... I don't know what I can possibly try to figure this one out..

Comment: Do you know the general formula for the volume of a pyramid?

Comment: not a 3 sided one..

Comment: It's $\frac 1 3 A H$ where $A$ is the area of the base of the pyramid and $H$ is its height. The number of sides doesn't matter. This also works for cones.

Comment: so how do I find A and H?

Comment: Are you able to draw the given pyramid? Do you understand what it looks like?

Comment: Take a "brick" and cut off one of its corners - that's the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1):

We use the technique of "volume by slicing."

Put the tetrahedron face down on the $x$-$y$ plane. For definiteness,  put the point where the mutually perpendicular planes meet at the origin. Put  the  edge of length $3$ along the positive $x$-axis, and the edge of length $4$ along the positive $y$-axis..

We find the cross-sectional area of a slice parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane, at **height** $z$.

The cross-section at height $z$ is a triangle similar to the triangle at the bottom, with legs scaled  by the factor $\frac{5-z}{5}$.

So the area of cross-section at height $z$ is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(3)(4)\left(  \frac{5-z}{5}\right)^2$.

To find the volume, integrate from $z=0$ to $z=5$. So the volume is
$$\int_{z=0}^5 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(3)(4)\left(  \frac{5-z}{5}\right)^2\.dz.$$
Integrate.

**Remark:** We chose a "calculus" approach because of the tag. There are ways to find the answer using basic geometry. If $3,4,5$ are replaced by $a,b,c$ the volume is $\frac{abc}{6}$.